# How can I organize make, model and generation of cars in Redis

Tags: database, data-structures, orm, redis

I need to store in DB (Redis) cars, its make, models and generations, with next requirements:

- I need be able to fetch all cars of exact makes, make and model or make, model and generation (For example all BMW - M3 - E30, or just all BMW -M3 and so on)
- I need to store rating of cars, such that I could fetch top X BMW, or top X BMW E30...

I designed some structure but it seems to be too huge. I have 4 object types: cars, makes, models, generations. They are grouped in tree structure. At the top of tree (root) is make, the one level down are models, next generations and at the bottom are cars. So makes, models and generations has sorted sets that contains there  models, generations and cars respectively, and cars, generations and models has simple string values, that points on generation, model and make respectively.

More that, make and models has it own sorted sets of cars.

How do you think about this? I'd like to union makes, model and generation to single object but do not now how.

Answer (score 0):

I would make your base object a car, which you could model as a hash with Make, Model, Generation, Rating and whatever other fields you need.  Then for each make, have a sorted set, e.g. `make:BMW => {car_id, car_id, car_id}`, where the score is equal to the rating.  Likewise, have model and generation sorted sets, also ordered by rating.  You can then use zunionstore/zinterstore to specify the exact set of properties you want, and pull data from the result by rating.  This makes it easy to add a new facet to query on - you can just create a new collection of zsets for, say, color and toss that into the same union/intersect engine.